# Swift inserting a cell in uicollectionview gives me an error

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return comments.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = commentSection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CommentCell
        return cell
}
```

And i have functions below this which inserts cells

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.comments.count, section: 0)
                    self.commentSection.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                    self.commentSection.reloadData()
 }
```

But whenever i run this code it prints this error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

And redirects me to AppDelegate file.Even though the error is very clearly written i can't understand the problem

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger and include the actual error and the line causing it in your question.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i put a breakpoint in all three lines inside of `DispatchQueue ` and it redirected me to Appdelegate file on `reloadData ` and didn't print anything except what is already in the question

Comment: You need to set up an __exception breakpoint__ as I already mentioned, not just a normal breakpoint. An exception breakpoint halts execution when an exception is thrown and lets you investigate the exact cause of the exception.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to modify the data source first before `inserting` or `deleting` a cell from collectionView.

```
self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.comments.count, section: 0)
    comments.append(your_object) //add your object to data source first
    self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @louis-ck : Am glad it did :) Always welcome buddy :)

Comment: Thank you a very useful answer.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari
any solution for deleteItems when removeAll objects from an array using performBatchUpdates?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 4**

```
onMain {


            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

            self.chatData.append(res)

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.chatData.count - 1, section: 0)

            self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])

            CATransaction.commit()

            print("scroll to index path: \(indexPath)")

            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom , animated: true)

            //self.collectionView.scrollToMaxContentOffset(animated: true, newHeight: 100)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you insert also additional object in your `comments` array before inserting items to collection view

Answer (score 0):

[performBatchUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates) is recommended way to insert items in collectionView. First update the data source and then call `performBatchUpdates` to insert a new item in collection view.

```
 //Update DataSource
 let newComment = "This is new comment"
 comments.append(newComment)

let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.comments.count - 1, section: 0)
var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = [indexPath]

// finally update the collection view
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
    collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
}, completion: nil)
```