# Is there a way to insert new items while loading more on ASCollectionNode Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: swift, asyncdisplaykit

I'm using ASCollectionNode horizontal scrolling and I'm trying to archive a scroll left to load more and insert items.but when I reach to the last item on the left the items are been inserted on the left instead of Right.

I implemented the insert like this..

```
 func addRowsIntoPhotoCollection(newPhotoCount newPhotos: Int) {
 let indexRange = (photoFeedModel.numberOfItems - newPhotos..<photoFeedModel.numberOfItems)
    let indexPaths = indexRange.map {  IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
    }) { (done) in
        if self.shouldScroll == true {
              self.scrollToBeginning()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try insert items on the end of the list, not on the leading.

Comment: How can I do that, can you show me an example, thanks

Comment: ur question related with UIKit->UICollectionView/UITableVIew, watch here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934664/887325

Comment: for Texture watch example: https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/blob/6428077e01cfbc56b4f482fb3149ce1c0e785e39/examples/Kittens/Sample/ViewController.m#L144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For add cells on the end of the list you have to create array of IndexPath's with rows grater then existingRows (collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)

```
  [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:existingRows + i inSection:0]];
```

swift version some like here:

```
var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []

// find number of kittens in the data source and create their indexPaths
var existingRows: Int = kittenDataSource.count + 1

for i in 0..<moarKittens.count {
    indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: existingRows + i, section: 0))
}

// add new kittens to the data source & notify table of new indexpaths
kittenDataSource.append(contentsOf: moarKittens)
if let indexPaths = indexPaths as? [IndexPath] {
    tableNode.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer, can I get a swift version of your answer. thanks a lot.